# What does -server option do?

Tags: json-rpc, server

What does the -server option do in bitcoin node? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin says 'Accept command line and JSON-RPC commands'. However I can't see any difference whatsoever. In both cases I'm able to curl my request as well as use the cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the help,

```
  -server
       Accept command line and JSON-RPC commands
```

You may however also have to check if this configuration parameter has been enabled by your local configuration, usually a file called bitcoin.conf, unless configured using the -conf parameter to bitcoind.

On linux builds, this should default to `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`, on Mac OS X `~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

In this file, you can explicitly configure the server as off using the server configuration parameter.

```
server=0
```

You can alternatively pass a parameter as 1 (enabled) or 0 (disabled)

```
bitcoind -server=0
```

You should not be able to access your server assuming this has been toggled to 0.

The headless daemon bitcoind has the JSON-RPC API enabled by default, the GUI bitcoin-qt has it disabled by default.

Comment: Didn't know it was enabled by default, they never mentioned it in the docs. This makes sense, I've never actually tried setting it to 0, only removing it. Thanks.

Comment: Pleasure. The documentation referring to this is here. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/JSON-RPC-interface.md

Please accept this answer if it has answered your question.